# What service for hosting multiple client websites?

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-hosting

I want to purchase a hosting service that allows me to host multiple sites with different log in. Its similar to a reseller host. I have been redirected to buying virtual hosting services from hostgator by one of their representative. If this is the way to go, do I have to know much about server administration to create multiple accounts and pointing domains to them? Or is it even possible?

Also, with Virtual hosting, that means I get databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this with a [Rackspace Cloud Sites](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/sites) account.  You can create different customer accounts and bill them through the portal.  You can get MSSQL or MySQL databases, and it supports PHP, Perl, Python, ASP.NET, and I believe classic ASP.

Note that this doesn't involve root access.

Comment: wow, they are expensive. Thanks though, I'll check them out. I have my eyes on: http://softsyshosting.com/Win08Reseller.aspx

Comment: They are designed for running a decent sized reselling operation, not a small site.  They might be larger than you are looking for.